# Google Script - Sheets - Dropdown Menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Was using this script to update a drop down menu based on the cell beside it changing value, however I now want that column to update based on a single cell on another sheet changing value, how would I update this code for that purpose?

```
 function Dropdown() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Window & Doors");
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Update Data")
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell()
  if (activeCell.getColumn() == 4 && activeCell.getRow() > 4) {
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    var makes = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
    if (makeIndex != 0) {
      var validationRange = datass.getRange(3, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The active cell would be the cell on the other page so it would become the sheet you would write it for.

Comment: is `DropDown()` an onEdit() trigger?

Comment: Currnently it's set in the Triggers to respond to any change and work.